Chrome extension - create dynamic declarative net request ruleset
I want to create a chrome extension to start using the declarativeNetRequest API. I saw that it need a ruleset where each rule will have this structure
{
  "id" : 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action" : { "type" : "block" },
  "condition" : {
    "urlFilter" : "abc",
    "initiatorDomains" : ["foo.com"],
    "resourceTypes" : ["script"]
  }
}

My idea is to have a dynammic set of rules that user can modify by adding or removing urls of websites. Is this possible, can I pass an obect instead of a static json file?

Yes, see updateDynamicRules and updateSessionRules in the documentation.
